# Webpack в терминале пишет: Невозможно загрузить файл C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\webpack.ps1

Tags: webpack

Пытался в терминале запустить webpack написал webpack, но терминал выдал это:

```
webpack : Невозможно загрузить файл C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\webpack.ps1, так как выполнение сценариев отключено в этой системе. Для получения дополнительных сведений см. about_Execution_Policies по адресу https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170 + webpack + ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : Ошибка безопасности: (:) [], PSSecurityException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

пытался исправить написал в терминал `npm install -g webpack webpack-cli` , но ответ точно тот же, Node.js установлен на данный момент стабильной версии, webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
```

`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: (
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') 
)
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

это связано с тем что у тебя включено выполнение сценариев в Windows.Открой powershell от имени администратора и введи Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted  и нажми Enter , затем тебя спросит точно ли ты хочешь это сделать и тепе просто надо ввести Y и нажать Enter.
Тк как именно это мне и помогло)